# c++ arrays using for loops to output rainfall statistics

Tags: c++

Write a program that reads in the rainfall for each of 12 months and outputs the month and the rainfall for the month. It should then output the month with the most rainfall, the month with the least rainfall, the total amount of rainfall for the year, and the average monthly rainfall. All rainfall amounts should be output with 2 significant digits after the decimal point.

The program should incorporate two parallel arrays: month of type string containing the month names, and rainfall of type double containing the rainfall in inches for the corresponding month.

Hint: Check slides 8 thru 10 of CS1336_Lect7c_Arrays_Compare_Parallel.pptx for examples.
The program should read in the rainfall amount for each month using a for loop.

The program should output the month right justified in a field width of 10 and the corresponding rainfall right justified in a field width of 6.

The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year and the average monthly rainfall.

The program should calculate the highest and lowest amounts and display the amounts and the corresponding month names.

Hint 1: Check slides 3 and 4 of CS1336_Lect7c_Arrays_Compare_Parallel.pptx for the code to find the lowest and the highest.

Hint 2: In addition, you will have to keep track of the index at which you found the highest and the lowest amount. Output the month name corresponding to the index. For example, if font rainfall[3] is the lowest rainfall, you will print font month[3] as the corresponding month.

Validation: Do not accept negative numbers for monthly rainfall figures.
When the input is as shown in Figure 1, your program should produce the output as shown in Figure 2.

Figure 1: (input)

```
3.2 .55 -1.2 -.9 2.2 .56 .24 .95 2.00 .35 5.9 1.1 2.8 .3
```

Figure 2: (output)

```
   January  3.20
  February  0.55
     March  2.20
     April  0.56
       May  0.24
      June  0.95
      July  2.00
    August  0.35
 September  5.90
   October  1.10
  November  2.80
  December  0.30

The most rainfall was 5.90 inches in September.
The least rainfall was 0.24 inches in May.
The total amount of rainfall for the year is 20.15 inches.
The average monthly rainfall for the year is 1.68 inches.
```

this is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int SIZE = 12;
   string months[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
   double rainfall [SIZE];
   double highest;
   double lowest;
   double total, average;

   cin >> rainfall[SIZE];

   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      cout << right << setw(10) << months[SIZE] << right <<setw(6) << rainfall[i] << endl;
   }

   for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      if (rainfall[i] > highest)
      {
         highest = rainfall[i];
      }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      if (rainfall[i] < lowest)
      {
         lowest = rainfall[i];
      }

   }
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      {

        total = rainfall[0] + rainfall[1] + rainfall[2] + rainfall[3] + rainfall[4];
        cout << "The total amount of rainfall for the year is " << total << " inches." << endl;
      }
      for(int i = 0; i << SIZE; i++)
      {
         average = total / SIZE;
         cout << "The average monthly rainfall for the year is " << average << " inches." << endl;
      }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what im doing wrong when i run it  i dont get a output

Comment: What is this line supposed to do `cin >> rainfall[SIZE];` ?

Comment: You can and have to use **one** loop, not five of them.

Comment: its supposed to read in the input that's shown

Comment: @LouisCastillo Guess you want to fill array `rainfall` with number of rainfalls?

Comment: @LouisCastillo It only reads one input. Did you mean to put it in a loop that reads 12 inputs, one for  each month?

Comment: yes. trying to read in the 12 inputs then output the month then the rainfall

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code and added comment on places I think you were off the line. Please try this out with your input and most importantly understand the changes made in the code and why is this fixing issues in your code. This way you won't just be coping/pasting the code but would also be learning in the process. Happy coding!

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 12;
    string months[]{ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    double rainfall[SIZE];
    double highest = 0.0;
    double lowest = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0, average = 0.0;

    double input;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ) //Dont increment i here since we want to ignore negative numbers.
    {
        cin >> input;
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        if (input > 0.0)
        {
            rainfall[i] = input;

            //for the first element assign lowest and highest to same value.
            if (i == 0)
            {
                highest = input;
                lowest = input;
            }

            if (input > highest) highest = input;
            if (input < lowest) lowest = input;
            total += rainfall[i]; //You need to keep adding all the months rainfall in total. ? why did you add only four and that too in loop?
            i++; //if the number is non negative increment i.
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << right << setw(10) << months[i] << right << setw(6) << rainfall[i] << endl;
    }

    average = total / SIZE;

    cout << "The total amount of rainfall for the year is " << total << " inches." << endl;
    cout << "The highest amount of rainfall for the year is " << highest << " inches." << endl;
    cout << "The lowest amount of rainfall for the year is " << lowest << " inches." << endl;
    cout << "The average monthly rainfall for the year is " << average << " inches." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instructions are fairly specific and sufficient. Just take them one at a time. For starters, you will need to validate you read `12` months of rainfall data into an array of `double`. Both to declare the array and validate the number of rainfall amounts read, you will need a constant. So:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define MONTHS 12   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
```

You have a choice where to declare your array of `string` holding the name of each `month`. You can declare the array local to `main()`, or you can declare the names as a global array (probably preferable). You will not be changing the names of each month, so you should qualify the array as `const`, e.g.

```
int main (void) {

    double rainfall[MONTHS] = {0},  /* declare/initialize variables */
        sum = 0, min = 10000, max = 0, avg = 0;
    const string month[] =  { "January", "February", "March", "April",
                        "May", "June", "July", "August",
                        "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    int mo = 0, maxmo = 0, minmo = 0;
```

Whenever you are reading multiple inputs in a loop, you want to control the loop based on a valid input and ensure that no stream errors occurred (`eofbit, failbit, badbit`) *before* you make use of your data. In your case, a single read-loop is all that is required to read the information, compute the `sum` for use with the `total` and `average` as well as determining the `max` and `min` and the months where each occurred (`maxmo`, and `minmo`). (**note:** that `min` is initialized sufficiently large so that it can handle determining the actual minimum. Initializing to `0` would not work)

```
    while ((cin >> rainfall[mo])) {     /* while good input */
        if (rainfall[mo] > 0) {         /* validate positive rainfall */
            sum += rainfall[mo];        /* increment sum by rainfall */
            if (rainfall[mo] < min)     /* set min and minmo */
                min = rainfall[mo], minmo = mo;
            if (rainfall[mo] > max)     /* set max and maxmo */
                max = rainfall[mo], maxmo = mo;
            mo++;
        }
    }
```

Now with your read loop complete, you would likely want to validate you actually have `12` months of rainfall data, and then compute the average e.g.:

```
    if (mo != MONTHS)   /* valdate 12 months of data read */
        cerr << "warning: only '" << mo << "' months data available.\n";

    avg = sum / (double)mo;
```

All that remains is formatting the output. The default justification is `right` so there is no need to include that format modifier, but you will need to use `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision()` to format your floating-point numeric output with two decimal places. You need only set each once unless you make changes to them in subsequent output. You can simply set:

```
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);   /* set fixed and precision(2) */
```

The floating-point output will now be output with two decimal places. All that remains is outputting the required information, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mo; i++)        /* output monthly data */
        cout << setw(10) << month[i] << setw(6) << rainfall[i] << '\n';

    /* output statistics */
    cout << "\nThe most rainfall was " << max << " inches in "
            << month[maxmo] << ".\n";
    cout << "The least rainfall was " << min << " inches in "
            << month[minmo] << ".\n";
    cout << "The total amount of rainfall for the year is "
            << sum << " inches.\n";
    cout << "The average monthly rainfall for the year is "
            << avg << " inches.\n";
```

(**note:** there is no actual need for multiple `cout` calls above, you can simply use a single `cout` and string all the information together)

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define MONTHS 12   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    double rainfall[MONTHS] = {0},  /* declare/initialize variables */
        sum = 0, min = 10000, max = 0, avg = 0;
    const string month[] =  { "January", "February", "March", "April",
                        "May", "June", "July", "August",
                        "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    int mo = 0, maxmo = 0, minmo = 0;

    while ((cin >> rainfall[mo])) {     /* while good input */
        if (rainfall[mo] > 0) {         /* validate positive rainfall */
            sum += rainfall[mo];        /* increment sum by rainfall */
            if (rainfall[mo] < min)     /* set min and minmo */
                min = rainfall[mo], minmo = mo;
            if (rainfall[mo] > max)     /* set max and maxmo */
                max = rainfall[mo], maxmo = mo;
            mo++;
        }
    }

    if (mo != MONTHS)   /* valdate 12 months of data read */
        cerr << "warning: only '" << mo << "' months data available.\n";

    avg = sum / (double)mo;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);   /* set fixed and precision(2) */
    for (int i = 0; i < mo; i++)        /* output monthly data */
        cout << setw(10) << month[i] << setw(6) << rainfall[i] << '\n';

    /* output statistics */
    cout << "\nThe most rainfall was " << max << " inches in "
            << month[maxmo] << ".\n";
    cout << "The least rainfall was " << min << " inches in "
            << month[minmo] << ".\n";
    cout << "The total amount of rainfall for the year is "
            << sum << " inches.\n";
    cout << "The average monthly rainfall for the year is "
            << avg << " inches.\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "3.2 .55 -1.2 -.9 2.2 .56 .24 .95 2.00 .35 5.9 1.1 2.8 .3" | \
./bin/rainfall
   January  3.20
  February  0.55
     March  2.20
     April  0.56
       May  0.24
      June  0.95
      July  2.00
    August  0.35
 September  5.90
   October  1.10
  November  2.80
  December  0.30

The most rainfall was 5.90 inches in September.
The least rainfall was 0.24 inches in May.
The total amount of rainfall for the year is 20.15 inches.
The average monthly rainfall for the year is 1.68 inches.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score -1):

1. Variable `SIZE` doesn't make any sense because you Know that year will always have 12 months. It only waste memory. If you want to use some kind of variable, use `#define SIZE 12`. Put it on the top under `#include` section.
2. Use can use only one loop for all tasks.
3. Last two loops also make no sense. If you want to calculate total amount of rainfall, put `total += rainfall[i];` inside loop.
4. `cin >> rainfall[SIZE];` also makes no sense and it's not correct. Why? With that line you acctually will put value in `rainfall[12];` but last index of `rainfall` is 11 not 12.
   To fill `rainfall` with values, put `cin >> ranfall[i];` inside loop. You have to use two different loops for filling `rainfall` and calculating all other stuff.

Comment: Strongly disagree with point 1. Vehemently disagree the solution to point one. A decent compiler will see that `const int SIZE = 12;`and sub in 12 where required. No memory cost and none of the macro substitution problems that come with `#define SIZE 12`. If you want to improve on `const int SIZE = 12;`, use `constexpr int SIZE = 12;`

Comment: I don't know what compiler he uses.